# Eclipse, import project but don't copy

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, svn, virtualbox

I use Linux as primary operating system and I also have to work on a Windows virtual machine with Eclipse 3.7.

We're working with subversion but with Linux I'm happily using git-svn with Emacs+magit, which works great.
So I would like to be able to work on the same code from both OS, and only do the real version control management on Linux.

So I had the following thought:
1. share the directory with virtualbox
2. create the projects pointing to the shared directory

Well that doesn't work, because the dumb thing wants to copy everything.
So I tried to use virtual folders which seemed a good idea, but now some scripts are badly failing because they don't find the hard-coded paths.

So I don't know anymore what to try, any idea?

EDIT:
My last attempt in the last edit would not work, so I have a simpler question.
Given a git/svn/whatever repository checkout, why can't I simply tell to Eclipse create a project *there* without touching the files?

Is it so hard for Eclipse to create it's .project in that position?
And since there is clearly no "supported" way to do it, is there maybe any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse modifies and compiles source in its workspace.  The first level of the workspace is the project directories, + a .metadata which is local only to that workspace instance.  Traditionally, the workspace contains the projects it works on.

Eclipse also supports 2 linked modes.  In one, when you create the project in the workspace you give it an absolute path to somewhere else on the file system.  This is handy if you have eclipse projects in a git repo, for example.

In the other mode, you create the project in your workspace  locally.  Then you link your folders (source, resources, whatever) to somewhere else on the filesystem.  This is useful for projects that don't want to save the eclipse specific files (.project, .classpath, etc) in their SCM.

You have to create a different workspace on each OS (there's no way around that).  But you could create the projects in each workspace and link to the common location (I don't recommend it, but it would be do-able).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I haven't seen this possibility when I first tried...  


So what I ended up doing is just do a checkout of the SVN repository, and I can make the two operating systems checkout communicate via the SVN repository, which is not really optimal but probably the easiest way...

Another thing I could do otherwise is to develop on Linux for example and set up an rsync daemon to synchronize the files I'm changing, so that they can appear on both OS before being committed.

Answer (score 7):

From my experience, the stages are the following (using Indigo version):
1. Create new empty project
2. Click File->import->file system
3. in the import window import file system, check the files you want into the new project folder
4. Click on advanced in the import window and tick "create links in workspace"

The new project should contain links to the original directory.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here and finally got a solution!

1) clone your repo but not directly to your workspace, in my case I used workspace2 instead of workspace.

2) On eclipse, import all the projects on workspace2, but don't mark the "copy files to workspace", so the source code is left on workspace2.

3) On git you will see changes appeared, on project.options files (only file date is changed) and in .path files (some lines changed its order). As all of them are irrelevant changes, reset the local branch discarding those changes.

Thats all, git sees no more changes and eclipse open the files properly!

I ran into a weird problem worth commenting here: after importing i went to "git gui" to see changes, and the first file changed was a "project.options" file that only changed its date but the diff was empty (as the content was unchanged). There is a bug on git that makes git gui enter on an infinite loop: while it detect changes on file and diff is empty, a rescan is performed, then the same change is detected and enter on a rescan loop.

There is a patch to solve this, but it was easier just to add a silly comment on that only file (not in all your project.options) and then "git gui" was happy again and i could reset the changes on the branch.